# Vuejs - Accordion

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create an accordion using vuejs.

I found some examples online, but what I want is different. For SEO purpose I use "is" and "inline-template", so the accordion is kind of static not fully created in Vuejs.

I have 2 problems/questions:

1) I need to add a class "is-active" on the component based on user interaction(clicks), because of this I receive the following error.

> Property or method "contentVisible" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

This probable because I need to set it at instance level. But "contentVisible" have a value (true or false) different for each component.

So I thought using at instance level an array of "contentVisible" and a props (pass thru instance) and custom events on child to update the instance values.

2) Could work but it is a static array. How can I make a dynamic array (not knowing the number of item components) ?

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div>
        <div class="accordion-item" is="item"  inline-template :class="{ 'is-active':  contentVisible}" >
            <div>
                <a @click="toggle" class="accordion-title"> Title A1</a>
                <div v-show="contentVisible" class="accordion-content">albatros</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item" is="item"  inline-template :class="{ 'is-active': contentVisible}" >
            <div>
                <a @click="toggle" class="accordion-title"> Title A2</a>
                <div v-show="contentVisible" class="accordion-content">lorem ipsum</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

```
var item = {
  data: function() {
      return {
          contentVisible: true
      }
  },

  methods: {
      toggle: function(){
          this.contentVisible = !this.contentVisible
      }
  }
}

new Vue({
    el:'.accordion',
    components: {
        'item': item
    }
})
```

---

**Update**
I create the following code but the custom event to send the modification from component to instance is not working, tabsactive is not changing

```
var item = {
  props: ['active'],
  data: function() {
      return {
          contentVisible: false
      }
  },
  methods: {
      toggle: function(index){
          this.contentVisible = !this.contentVisible;
          this.active[index] = this.contentVisible;
          **this.$emit('tabisactive', this.active);**
          console.log(this.active);
      }
  }
}

new Vue({
    el:'.accordion',
    data: {
      tabsactive: [false, false]
    },
    components: {
        'item': item
    }
})
```

---

```
<div class="accordion" **@tabisactive="tabsactive = $event"**>
        <div class="accordion-item" is="item"  inline-template :active="tabsactive" :class="{'is-active': tabsactive[0]}">
            <div>
                <a @click="toggle(0)" class="accordion-title"> Title A1</a>
                <div v-show="contentVisible" class="accordion-content">albatros</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item" is="item"  inline-template :active="tabsactive" :class="{'is-active': tabsactive[1]}">
            <div>
                <a @click="toggle(1)" class="accordion-title" > Title A2</a>
                <div v-show="contentVisible" class="accordion-content">lorem ipsum</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On point 1:

You have to define `contentVisible` as a vue instance variable, as you have accessed it with vue directive [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show), it searches this in vue [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data), [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad), [methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers), etc, and if it does not find any reference, it throws this error.

As your `accordion` element is associated with the parent component, you may have to add `contentVisible` data there, like following:

```
new Vue({
    el:'.accordion',
    data: {
       contentVisible: true
    }
    components: {
        'item': item
    }
})
```

If you have multiple items, you may use some other technique to show one of them, like have a data variable `visibleItemIndex` which can change from 1 to n-1, where n is number of items.

In that case, you will have `v-show="visibleItemIndex == currentIndex"` in the HTML.

You can as well have hash for saving which index are to de displayed and which to be collapsed.

On point 2:

You can use [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for) if you have dynamic arrays. you can see the documentation here.

Comment: 1) I know (I said that) but contentVisible is different for each component.   2) I use "inline-template" and "is",   to have the content in the html source for SEO purpose(see the code), so I can't use v-for in this case, I need somehow to "read" the number of components from html.

Comment: @user3541631 but there is no contentVisible defined  in the `new Vue()`.

Comment: yes it isn't, but if I define in Vue() it can have 2 values: true or false(visible/hide). If I have 10 items (controlled thru contentVisible prop) how can I control their visibility independently?

Comment: your solution works if when I open one item/panel I close the others, but if I what multiple to be open at the same time ? another thing, in the front end can be added a number of items that I don't know (code generated by back-end).
So I don't know "n"
if I don't know n, how do I get it after the code is generate by backend ?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="index in list" :key="index._id">

                <button @click="contentVisible === index._id ? contentVisible = false : contentVisible = index._id">{{ index.title }}</button>

                <p v-if='contentVisible === index._id'>{{ index.item }}</p>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "sameName",
        data() {
            return {
                contentVisible: false,
                list: [
                    {
                    _id: id1,
                    title: title1,
                    item: item1
                    },
                    {
                    _id: id2,
                    title: title2,
                    item: item2
                    }
                ]
            };
        },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: it works for me as well. However, I want to open always the first index and when I click the other one it should open and collapse the first index at the same time. can you please suggest me how can I achieve it with this code?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a real hard time understanding what exactly it is you want or why you would want it, but I think this does it?

```js
Vue.component('accordion-item', {
  template: '#accordion-item',
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      if(this.contentVisible){
       return
      }
      if(this.$parent.activeTab.length >= 2){
       this.$parent.activeTab.shift()
      }
      this.$parent.activeTab.push(this)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    contentVisible() {
      return this.$parent.activeTab.some(c => c === this)
    }
  }
})

const Accordion = Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      activeTab: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleToggle($event) {
      this.activeTab = []
    }
  }
})

document.querySelectorAll('.accordion').forEach(el => new Accordion().$mount(el))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-item" :class="{ 'is-active':  contentVisible}">
      <a href="#" @click="toggle" class="accordion-title"><slot name="title"></slot></a>
      <div v-show="contentVisible" class="accordion-content" @click="$emit('toggle', $event)">
        <slot name="content"></slot>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

  <div class="accordion">
    <accordion-item @toggle="handleToggle">
      <p slot="title">a title</p>
      <p slot="content">there are words here</p>
    </accordion-item>
    <accordion-item @toggle="handleToggle">
      <p slot="title">titles are for clicking</p>
      <p slot="content">you can also click on the words</p>
    </accordion-item>
    <accordion-item @toggle="handleToggle">
      <p slot="title">and another</p>
      <p slot="content">only two open at a time!</p>
    </accordion-item>
    <accordion-item @toggle="handleToggle">
      <p slot="title">and #4</p>
      <p slot="content">amazing</p>
    </accordion-item>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want to create an accordion.
The html is generated by backend (python) not Vue, like in your answer. 
This is why I use “inline-template” and is=”item” (where “item” is the component name).

I need to add the “is-active” class to the component div, when the div content inside component is active/display.

For that I need to modify the parent property tabsactive from child using custom event, and is not working. Check the following code:

this.$emit('tabisactive', this.active)
@tabisactive="tabsactive = $event"
:class="{'is-active': tabsactive[1]}

Comment: Using `this.$parent`is anti-pattern, an escape hatch. Therefore not recommended.